# Angular JS routing not working - no request is being made

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new with AngularJS - I try to test the routing functionality, but the following code doesn't take any action - I don't see any request to the server. What am I doing wrong here ?

```
<html ng-app="myModule">
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.2/angular-route.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    var firstModule = angular.module('myModule', ['ngRoute']);

    firstModule.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
        var array = [{ id: 123 }];
        $scope.getEntities = function () { return array; };
    });

    firstModule.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when(
          "/status/:id", {
              templateUrl: "routesDemo/one"
          });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <ul ng-repeat="item in getEntities()">
       <li><a class="btn btn-primary btn-mini" href="#/status/{{ item.id }}">Details</a></li>
   </ul>
</body>
```

### EDIT

I saw I didn't use the `<div ng-view></div>`. Now it works

Comment: did you try using the `ng-href` tag?

Comment: no console errors appears. I used the ng-href tag, with no result